# Threading with tkinter running code before I press button

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter, beautifulsoup

I am running a simple script in tkinter in which i define an entry field, and then on the press of a button, it gets the text inside the entry field. This was working fine, but then I added threading, and the function that the button is supposed to run is running before I press the button, and is giving me an error saying that there is nothing in the entry field.
Is there any way to fix this? Here is an example of my code (not my actual code but causes the same error):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import urllib.request
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
from tkinter import filedialog
import tkinter.simpledialog as simpledialog
import os
import threading
import keyboard


def run():
    url = Link.get()
    req = requests.get(str(url))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req, "html.parser")

root = tk.Tk(className="Main Window")
root.geometry("625x350")
root.configure(bg="grey35")
root.resizable(False, False)

def paste():
    keyboard.press_and_release('ctrl + v')


m = tk.Menu(root, tearoff=False)
m.add_command(label="Paste", command=paste)

Link = tk.Entry(root, bd=5, width="50")
Link.grid(row=0, column=1)


def do_popup(event):
    try:
        m.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root)
    finally:
        m.grab_release()


Link.bind("<Button-3>", do_popup)

Run = tk.Button(root, text="Run", bg="grey", fg="black", width="30", height="2",
                command=threading.Thread(target=run).start())
Run.grid(row=1, column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Change `command=threading.Thread(target=run).start()` to `command=lambda: threading.Thread(target=run).start()`. Also you shouldn't use the `keyboard` or `threading` module when using `tkinter` unless you know what you are doing. Sometimes `tkinter` crashes if you call it from another thread.

Comment: Also look at `<tkinter.Tk>.clipboard_get()`, `<tkinter.Tk>.clipboard_append(...)` and `<tkinter.Tk>.clipboard_clear()`. You can use those to replace the need for the `keyboard` library